# Increasing Sequence of Simply Connected Domains with Riemann Mapping Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, connectedness

Let $\{D_m\}$ be an increasing sequence of simply connected domains, and let $\phi_m$ be the Riemann map of $D_m$ onto the open unit disk $\mathbb{D}$, normalized so that $\phi_m(z_0) = 0$ and $\phi'(z_0) > 0$ for some fixed $z_0 \in D_1$. Let $D$ be the union of the $D_m$'s. Show that if $D$ is the entire complex plane, then the $\phi_m$'s are eventually defined on the disk $\{|z| \leq R\}$ and converge there uniformly to $0$. Otherwise, $D$ is simply connected and the $\phi_m$'s are eventually defined on each compact subset of $D$ and converge there uniformly to the Riemann map $\phi$ of $D$ onto $\mathbb{D}$ satisfying $\phi(z_0) = 0$ and $\phi'(z_0) > 0$.

Obviously I'm missing something here. I feel the first conclusion would always be true. This is map to the unit disk. So wouldn't every point "eventually" (more like right away) be on the disk $\{|z| \leq R\}$ since they are being mapped to the unit disk? What am I missing here and how would I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement you are asking about is

> ... the $\phi'_m$'s are eventually defined on the disc $\{|z| \le R\}$ ...

What it means for $\phi'_m$ to be defined on the disc $\{|z| \le R\}$ is that $\{|z| \le R\}$ is a subset of the domain of definition of $\phi'_m$. This can be written more succinctly as $\{|z| \le R\} \subset D_m$, because $D_m$ *is* the domain of definition of $\phi'_m$ (which is identical to the domain of definition of the Riemann map $\phi_m$).

So, what that statement means is that

> ... there exists $M \in \mathbb N$ such that if $m \ge M$ then $\{|z| \le R\} \subset D_m$.

Actually this particular statement has nothing to do with $\phi'_m$, and it has nothing to do with simple connectivity: it is true using only the assumption that $D_1 \subset D_2 \subset D_3 \subset \cdots$ is an increasing sequence of open subsets such that $D = \bigcup_{m=1}^\infty D_m = \mathbb C$.

The proof is a simple application of compactness. First, the closed ball $B_R = \{|z| < R\}$ is compact. Next, $\{D_m\}$ is an open cover of $B_R$, because it is an open cover of the larger set $D=\mathbb C$. Applying compactness of $B_R$, there exists a finite subcover $\{D_{m_1},...,D_{m_K}\}$ of $B_R$, meaning such that $B_R \subset D_{m_1} \cup \cdots \cup D_{m_K}$. But we can rearrange the indices to be in increasing order $m_1 < m_2 < ... < m_K$ and it follows that $D_{m_1} \cup \cdots \cup D_{m_K} = D_{m_K}$. So for all $m \ge M = m_K$ it follows that
$$D_m \supset D_{m_K} = D_{m_1} \cup \cdots \cup D_{m_K} \supset B_R = \{|z| \le R\}
$$

Comment: There was a typo. It is not the $\phi'_m$'s. It is the $\phi_m$'s. Sorry about that

Comment: I thought that might be the case. But that doesn't matter for the question that you asked, because that question was solely about the nested sequence of domains $D_1 \subset D_2 \subset \cdots$, and $D_m$ is the domain of definition of both $\phi_m$ and $\phi'_m$ (for each $m$).

Comment: After looking this over this morning, I think I understand the proof. I do see one part missing though, what about the uniform convergence of the $\phi_m$'s? Also, what about the second part? You mentioned it has nothing to do with simple connectivity. With that said, how would the second part follow if $D \neq \mathbb{C}$? It mentions that $D$ would be simply connected in the otherwise case.

Comment: It didn't seem that you were asking about all those other points as well. So I restricted my answer to the actual questions that you asked in your second paragraph; simple connectivity is irrelevant to *those* questions. Simple connectivity is certainly relevant to the further conclusions of your first paragraph.

Comment: I'll just say, very briefly, that what's left is to apply the theory of normal families to get uniform convergence, and then apply Montel's theorem to get that the limit is holomorphic. That part could well be laid out carefully in whatever source you are looking at.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure how to go about that. It seems I've already gotten as much out of this as I can, so I'll just accept the answer and move on. If you decide to write out the rest I'm sure others will appreciate it. I am going to move on though. Thanks again!